# Can't host ASMX web service on iis

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, iis-6, asmx

i create a web service in a web site project(in vs 2010). in visual studio, when i run this web site i can see this web service, like this:

[image]

the body of web service is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

public WebService () {

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}

[WebMethod]
public int Plus(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

[WebMethod]
public int Multiply(int x, int y)
{
    return x * y;
}
```

}

i host this web site on iis 6 by this steps:

- 1) click add new web site option by right click on WebSites node in
  IIS.

  2) assigning a port to it (for ex 1919 port)

  3) specifying physical path of web site in next step

  4) specifying access level permissions

  5) finish

and now i want to call below address , and give this error:
[image]

i restart iis, and not happened anything.

i want to use this web service locally, why this error happened? how to solve it?

Comment: Your error is invisible to me.

Comment: this is:  The page cannot be displayed
You have attempted to execute a CGI, ISAPI, or other executable program from a directory that does not allow programs to be executed.

Please try the following:

    Contact the Web site administrator if you believe this directory should allow execute access.

HTTP Error 403.1 - Forbidden: Execute access is denied.
Internet Information Services (IIS)

Comment: Note that ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN. Also, it's generally a bad idea to use web site projects, especially not for web services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select  "Execute (such as ISAPI application or CGI)" this check box while creating virtual directory

Answer (score 1):

you probably just need to enable the .NET Web Extensions. See this image.

[image]

If not, make sure that the directory that your webservice is in is marked as an application, and set to execute. Make sure as well that the asmx handler is setup by running

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
```

Comment: i check this option and it is allowed